# Send email from dummy user in jenkins using email-ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have configured email-ext plugin configuration in Jenkins with the valid SMTP settings.   When I send the email after completion of job it uses above user(from:). Instead of that I want to show this mail is from dummy-user@dummy-domain.com.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In SMTP server just give your company mail domain. `mail.company.com`. It worked for me.